# What is the fastest way to load a large amount of Neo4j data from a remote machine?

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j

I am getting a set of fairly large files, with a max of about 1 Million lines of Neo4j code. The input files look like this,

```
MERGE (:ProgNode:compilationUnit {nodeSeq:0,name:'Too Long to Display',quViolations:0,quVioDensity:0.0,quChange:False,location:0,level:'0',szlocs:1,eieo:False});
```

And then eventually, the connections

```
MATCH (a:ProgNode),(b:ProgNode) WITH a,b WHERE a.nodeSeq = 20502 AND b.nodeSeq = 20504 MERGE ...
```

Average file size is around 200,000 lines but some bump up to the million mark.

I am using the python interface right now with a delay in processing when it "hiccups"

```
        for line in FI:
        counter +=1
        if counter >= startrow:
            if (counter % 500) == 0:
                print("     line %s was reached" % counter)
            firstword = line.split()[0]    
            if firstword == "MATCH" and matchflag == False:
                print("  Created %s nodes\n" % counter)
                print("  Beginning links @ %s\n" % str(time.asctime()))
                matchflag = True
            elif firstword == "CREATE" and createflag == False:
                print("  Beginning Node Creation\n")
                createflag = True
            elif firstword == "//" and postflag == False:
                print("  %s  @ %s\n" % (line[:-2], str(time.asctime())))
                postflag = True    
            try:
                if firstword != "//":
                    graphDB_Session.run(line)
            except:
                print("      Line %s was an issue. wait, then retry ...." % counter,end="")
                time.sleep(8)
                graphDB_Session.run(line)
                FO.write(line)
                print("success!")
                continue
```

its fairly reliable if slow. I'd rather not unformat and go to CSV but if its faster, so be it. But given the situation, any suggestions on speed ? Should I FTP it to the server and run from there ? Is there a faster API ?

Based on your comments, is this how you thought it should look ? It does throw an error for  invalid literal for int() with base 10: "MERGE (:ProgNode:compilationUnit so I might still not be understanding.

```
    print("Starting Node load @ %s\n" % time.asctime())
# Create nodes
store_embedding = """
UNWIND $data as row
MATCH (n)
WHERE id(n) = row.id
SET n.embedding = row.embedding
"""
embeddings = []
with graphDB_Driver.session() as graphDB_Session:
    for record in FI:
        id = record
        # Prepare data
        embeddings.append({'id':int(id), 'embedding': [float(x) for x in list(model.wv[id])]})
    # Store embeddings to Neo4j    
    session.run(store_embedding, {'data': embeddings})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to avoid is to run a session for each line, you want to batch them in batches of like 1000 for example, and then use the `UNWIND` statement. I don't really know what are you doing as your lines look like cypher statements, which is weird. You could use APOC do run many statements in a single transaction I suppose.

I have here an example of how you would preprocess a dataset in Python and import it to Neo4j.

```
store_embedding = """
UNWIND $data as row
MATCH (n)
WHERE id(n) = row.id
SET n.embedding = row.embedding
"""
embeddings = []
with driver.session() as session:
    for record in data:
        id = record
        # Prepare data
        embeddings.append({'id':int(id), 'embedding': [float(x) for x in list(model.wv[id])]})
    # Store embeddings to Neo4j    
    session.run(store_embedding, {'data': embeddings})
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit ? It looks like you are trying to cast string into an integer. 
id = record
embeddings.append({'id':int(id), 'embedding': [float(x) for x in list(model.wv[id])]})
and thats throwing an Invalid literal for int() base 10

Comment: You can see that I iterate over data and preprocess it basically. This completely depends on your use case. The main part I wanted to show is that I run only a single transaction at the end which is not part of the loop. So do not run a single transaction for each row, but try to batch a single transaction for like 100 or 1000 rows.

Comment: And why is it weird that they look like cypher statements ( which of course they are) ? Other than CSV, I didnt think there was a choice on that one

Comment: Maybe weird is not the best wording, unusual is better :) batch your cypher commands and execute them with apoc.runMany for example

Comment: I am still a bit unclear on the 'id':int(id) conversion as it seems to be trying to convert the record into an integer. Sorry - thats just not clicking

Comment: Tomaz - Can you send me an email ( Bill.dickenson@veriprism.llc) - I have a few follow ups to this that and this is probably not a good forum for that. Thanks